# Trying to make dynamically created element draggable

Tags: dynamic, input, element, draggable

I'm trying to create a dynamic input element that is draggable. Now the problem is I create an element but when I use something like

```
$("#in"+index.toString()).draggable({cancel:true});
```

after I append it to the container div, it's not working. Basically it's not working for the dynamically created input element of a certain id. Here's the code and please feel free to point out problems. I could really use some help on this one. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/ithril/hRCun/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new element that is not bound to the UI functions. I would suggest using `clone(true,true)` and then changing the parameters of the cloned element as need be. You can learn more about clone here. http://api.jquery.com/clone/